# JQuery/Javascript/DOM Visibility Event

Tags: jquery

Is there an event in JQuery, Javascript, or the DOM in general that I can subscribe to that will notify me when an element become visible or invisible (display:none)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [onHide() type event in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857900/onhide-type-event-in-jquery)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There are events for DOMAttrModified and onpropertychange (IE) that can track DOM element changes and fire an event.

Wrote about this with a jQuery plug-in that allows monitoring changes to CSS styles here:

http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/478985.aspx

This might be just what you need as you could do something like:

```
$("#myControl").watch("display,visibility", function() { showStatus("changed...") });
```

Comment: Use this inside anonymous function to see if item is visible or not: $(this).is(':visible');

Comment: Don't forget about `opacity`. I like the idea :)