# Call Javascript function when a div turns from visibility : hidden

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, visibility, onfocus

I want to call a Javascript function when a div is turned from "visibilty : hidden" to "visibility : none;"

Also note that I don't have control over the script which turns this style property of the div. I just want to hook into this. Any possibilities? Or like `onFocus()` etc?

UPDATE : I do not want to use JQuery or other frameworks. Is it possible?

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941113/jquery-javascript-dom-visibility-event

Comment: Dup again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397251/event-detect-when-css-property-changed-using-jquery

Comment: ps your answer is in those previously asked questions.

Comment: am sorry, I didnt mention that I don't wanna use JQuery or other frameworks.. I will update my question

Comment: @Xinxua: look at the answers to those questions, not just the titles. **They don't use jQuery**.

Answer (score 0):

In mootools you can create custom events. However, I would do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('foo').triggerMyEvent = function() {
  if (this.style.visibility == 'hidden') {
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

And add a call to the object's 'triggerMyEvent' method in whatever code switches the object's visibility.

Answer (score 0):

There's the `propertychange` event in IE that responds to changes in an element's properties, including properties of its `style` object. However, this only works on properties set directly on the element's `style` object and doesn't work for CSS changes (e.g. changing the class of the element's parent element) that indirectly affect the element's style. Using the DOMAttrModified in other browsers will work similarly and has the same shortcomings, so this may not be workable for you.