# onHide() type event in jQuery

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

Does anyone know of an `onHide()` event or something similar in jQuery?

I tried:

```
$(this).bind('hide', function(){
    console.log('asdasda')
})
```

But apparently that doesn't work.

**Edit:**
Just to clarify, it's being hidden using CSS `display:none`.
I'm aware of the callback function but as I'm not hiding it (the CSS is) I can't use it.
For what it's worth, I need to check when a dropdown is visible. It's being shown by the following CSS:

```
ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941113/jquery-javascript-dom-visibility-event

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no "hide" event for any HTML element in the DOM.  How are you "hiding" your elements?  Are you using CSS to change the display or visibility?

If you're using display:none to hide an element, you can't detect when CSS changes.  In IE, you can detect when a property changes but that doesn't extend to style values.  You'll need to throw an event or do whatever the event is doing at the time the CSS display is changed.

Comment: Using [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) it is now possible to listen to changes of attributes on dom nodes, including the style and class attribute I believe...so the answer to the question should be *yes*.

Comment: If you are using jQuery's `.css('display','none')` it should be supported in https://github.com/hypesystem/jquery.hide-event.js - just listen for "hide" events.

Answer (score 75):

There isn't a native or built in "hide" event but if you are using jQuery to hide it you can easily add a hide event:

```
var _oldhide = $.fn.hide;
$.fn.hide = function(speed, callback) {
    $(this).trigger('hide');
    return _oldhide.apply(this,arguments);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not hiding it, it's being hidden by my CSS.

Comment: This is quite a cool hack, but personally Id rather override core jq

Comment: Cool as long as the element is hidden using `$.hide()`;

Comment: I have started a project on GitHub to provide a more general-purpose solution: https://github.com/hypesystem/jquery.hide-event.js

Comment: I think [this](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-trigger-custom-event-show-hide-element/) is a slightly more elegant version of the same solution, as it doesn't leave a var hanging around. Plus one for early delivery!

Answer (score 16):

You can pass call back function in hide function.

```
function iAmCallBackForHide() { 
             alert('I am visible after hide'); 
}
$('#clickMeToHide').hide( iAmCallBackForHide );
```

Comment: This is the most proper answer. bang bang!

Comment: This is nice, just bear in mind that when you specify a callback function to hide (or show) they become animation functions with a default duration of 400ms.
Specify `0` if that's a problem: `$('#clickMeToHide').hide( 0, iAmCallBackForHide );`

Answer (score 5):

For anyone finding this post two years later:

You know exactly when the menu is visible, right?! The CSS rule tells you. So instead of relying on onShow or onHide events, you can *recreate the very same rule* using jQuery and rely on the very same 'hover event':

```
$('ul li').hover(function () {
    // Whatever you want to do 'onShow'
}, function () {
    // Whatever you want to do 'onHide'
});
```

Also, your script now acts independent of any stylesheet, so that presentation details do not dictate website behavior (nice).

Comment: This solution works if the the mouse is the only input. If the application supports a keyboard or touch interface then it's not sufficient.

Comment: True, @jbustamovej, but the li:hover from the question will not work either. Good point though.

Answer (score 4):

In jQuery 3 exposes a "hide" and "show" events.

```
$(document).on("hide", function() { 
    console.log("browser page has been hidden");
});
```

Comment: This is nice, but I am not running 3, but this is good for futuristic folks :D

Answer (score 2):

I have recently made a plugin to detect when an element gets hidden or shown in any way ( by core javascript or inspector or jQuery hide / show ).

[pratik916/jQuery-HideShow](https://github.com/pratik916/jQuery-HideShow)

> This extension keeps watching on element for visibility change. once changed it will emmit an event where you can handle your stuff

```
$("#test_hidden").hideShow(function(e, visibility){
    if(visibility == "shown") {
        console.log("Element is visible");
    } else {
        console.log("Element is hidden");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy-pizy, use [DOM mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver) for this:

JS:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    console.log('div hide event fired!');
  });
  var target = document.querySelector('.mydiv');
  observer.observe(target, {
    attributes: true
  });
```

HTML:

```
<div class='mydiv'>
</div>
```

Here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/qs01umdw/2/

Comment: This triggers on each change of that div. It will also trigger if you change e.g. the CSS or add a class. In order for it to trigger only on e.g. a class change, you'll need to add conditions: `if(mutations.attributeName === "class" && mutations.classList.contains("hidden") {` ...

Not *that* Easy-pizy, but still doable.

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful on some use cases:
Using waitUntilExists jquery plugin ([How to wait until an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists)) you can detect when the value changes:

```
$(li:hidden).waitUntilExists(function(){                        
   // your code when it is hidden 
}, /*onlyOnce = */ true);
```

I used it for detecting when a loading gif was hidden.