# How to wait until an element exists for dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

In dojo, is there a way to get notified when an element of certain class (or contain certain text) has been created?

There is an almost exactly the same question asked in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists) for jQuery. But I'd like to know if there is a similar solution for dojo. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like somebody was thinking the same thing... http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.dojo.devel/12516/focus=12559

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For dojo 1.7, based on the JQuery answer, I would do :

```
require(["dojo/on", "dojo/_base/array"], function(on, array){
    on(dojo.doc, "DOMNodeInserted", function(evt){
        var classes = dojo.attr(evt.target, "class").split(" ");
        if (array.indexOf(classes, "myclass") > -1) {
            console.debug("Inserted node with class myclass", evt.target);
        }
    });
});
```