# iframe CSS Override for New Twitter Widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to customise the new Twitter widget, but having some problems with the CSS and can't seem to override theirs on this new one. I've tried searching for solutions but can't find any that match.

[Here's my page](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/nightlife/bars/lot-75-cafe-bar-412.html) with the widget in the right-nav and the tweaked CSS for the .timeline class:

```
.timeline {
margin-bottom:0;
border:0 !important;
border-radius:0 !important;
-webkit-border-radius:0;
-moz-border-radius:0;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="bg">
<h3 class="twitter">Twitter News</h3>
<div id="twitter">
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/" data-widget-id="268336500536647680">Tweets by </a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
</div></div>
```

I've started using !important declarations and tried the main #twitter id to override, but neither works.

Any ideas much appreciated.

**I apparently need to edit the iframe somehow, but not sure how - if anyone has a clearer idea how I can do that with my code (as opposed to a tutorial) that would be great. I also need to change the iframe width..

Answer (score 27):

I managed to do this with javascript (I use jQuery in my application!). You have to apply the styles after the iframe load (I did not find a valid "loaded" event, so I use a polling strategy).

```
// Customize twitter feed
var hideTwitterAttempts = 0;
function hideTwitterBoxElements() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        if ( $('[id*=twitter]').length ) {
        $('[id*=twitter]').each( function(){
            if ( $(this).width() == 220 ) {
                $(this).width( 198 ); //override min-width of 220px
            }
            var ibody = $(this).contents().find( 'body' );
            ibody.width( $(this).width() + 20 ); //remove scrollbar by adding width

            if ( ibody.find( '.timeline .stream .h-feed li.tweet' ).length ) {
            ibody.find( '.timeline' ).css( 'border', 0 );
            ibody.find( '.timeline .stream' ).css( 'overflow-x', 'hidden' );
            ibody.find( '.timeline .stream' ).css( 'overflow-y', 'scroll' );
            ibody.find( '.timeline-header').hide();
            ibody.find( '.timeline-footer').hide();
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
        }
        hideTwitterAttempts++;
        if ( hideTwitterAttempts < 3 ) {
            hideTwitterBoxElements();
        }
    }, 1500);
}

// somewhere in your code after html page load
hideTwitterBoxElements();
```

Comment: +1 well played ;-) not sure if this will work in all cases, but have managed to hide the avatar in Firefox test case

Comment: You can use the function defined here http://stackoverflow.com/a/13709125/893510 to do: $("iframe#twitter-widget-0").waitUntilExists(function(){ //Formatting });

Comment: if you don't want to use setTimeout, you can use: https://gist.github.com/buu700/4200601

Answer (score 7):

This is without jQuery for anyone interested.

UPDATED with much better solution that doesn't rely on polling and therefore doesn't have a flash of unstyled layout on occasion:

```
twttr.events.bind('rendered',function(){
  [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('iframe.twitter-timeline')).forEach(function(e,i,a){
    var fE = e.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('timeline-footer');
    if(fE.length){
      fE[0].style.backgroundColor='transparent';
    }
  });
});
```

old version:

```
// Customize twitter feed                                                                              
var hideTwitterAttempts = 0;                                                                           
function hideTwitterBoxElements() {                                                                    
    setTimeout( function() {                                                                           
        var list = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');                                            
        if (list.length ) {                                                                            
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(                                                              
                list,                                                                                  
                function(element){                                                                     
                    var footerE = element.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('timeline-footer')[0];
                    footerE.style.backgroundColor="transparent";                                       
                });                                                                                    
        }                                                                                              
        hideTwitterAttempts++;                                                                         
        if ( hideTwitterAttempts < 3 ) {                                                               
            hideTwitterBoxElements();                                                                  
        }                                                                                              
    }, 1500);                                                                                          
}                                                                                                      
hideTwitterBoxElements();
```

Comment: I am quite ameaturish when come to JS... can you explain the code? specifically the hideTwitterAttempt variable?

Comment: Oh, `hideTwitterAttempts` simply puts a limit (3) on how many times I try and hide the background. It's a simple counter variable, I just don't want the page to hang (waiting for the too-much-recursion error to be thrown) if something goes wrong (if twitter changes its widget for example) so I limit the script's potential runtime. The `Array.prototype.forEach.call` syntax is because `document.getElementsByTagName` returns a nodelist instead of an array, so I can't call `foreach` directly.

Comment: Hi

I tried out a modified version of your answer, on IE9. This is what i have `function(element){                                                                     
                    var foo= element.contentDocument.getElementsByClassName('tweet-actions')[0];
                    foo.style.display="none";                                       
                }); 
`

This does not work in IE 8 OR 9. But it does on Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Could you show me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I'm not an IE expert, so my first instinct is that it's due to some non standard behaviour in IE's JS interpreter or perhaps their security policy. Can you open the developer tools, reload the page and let me know of any errors that get reported? This might be hard to debug in the comments here so you may want to open a question and link to it in a reply here.

Comment: Question for you Camden - I tried this with targeting .header to get rid of the tweet author info (they're all from the same user) and it only seems to work for the first one. Is there a way to target all?

Comment: I specifically only alter the first element of the results in my code (see the zero index: [0]) so to hit them all, replace the index with a forEach() call and put your logic in the closure.

Answer (score 6):

I adapted the code from @Sebastiaan Ordelman and added some comments (referring to values from old API).  This was my attempt to match the old API in a short amount of time. Place this code after your new copy and paste code from the new twitter widget.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var hideTwitterAttempts = 0;
function hideTwitterBoxElements() {
    setTimeout( function() {
        if ( $('[id*=twitter]').length ) {
        $('[id*=twitter]').each( function(){
            var ibody = $(this).contents().find( 'body' );

            if ( ibody.find( '.timeline .stream .h-feed li.tweet' ).length ) {
            ibody.find( '.customisable-border' ).css( 'border', 0 );
            ibody.find( '.timeline' ).css( 'background-color', '#004A7B' ); //theme: shell: background:
            ibody.find( 'ol.h-feed' ).css( 'background-color', '#0575A1' ); //theme: tweets: background:
            ibody.find( 'ol.h-feed' ).css( 'border-radius', '5px 5px 5px 5px' );
            ibody.find( 'li.tweet' ).css( 'border-bottom', '1px dotted #FFFFFF' ); //theme: tweets: color:
            ibody.find( 'li.tweet' ).css( 'color', '#FFFFFF' ); //theme: tweets: color:
            ibody.find( '.customisable:link' ).css( 'color', '#07E0EB' ); //theme: tweets: links:
            ibody.find( '.footer' ).css( 'visibility', 'hidden' ); //hide reply, retweet, favorite images
            ibody.find( '.footer' ).css( 'min-height', 0 ); //hide reply, retweet, favorite images
            ibody.find( '.footer' ).css( 'height', 0 ); //hide reply, retweet, favorite images
            ibody.find( '.avatar' ).css( 'height', 0 ); //hide avatar
            ibody.find( '.avatar' ).css( 'width', 0 ); //hide avatar
            ibody.find( '.p-nickname' ).css( 'font-size', 0 ); //hide @name of tweet
            ibody.find( '.p-nickname' ).css( 'visibility', 'hidden' ); //hide @name of tweet
            ibody.find( '.e-entry-content' ).css( 'margin', '-25px 0px 0px 0px' ); //move tweet up (over @name of tweet)
            ibody.find( '.dt-updated' ).css( 'color', '#07E0EB' ); //theme: tweets: links:
            ibody.find( '.full-name' ).css( 'margin', '0px 0px 0px -35px' ); //move name of tweet to left (over avatar)
            ibody.find( 'h1.summary' ).replaceWith( '<h1 class="summary"><a class="customisable-highlight" title="Tweets from fundSchedule" href="https://twitter.com/fundschedule" style="color: #FFFFFF;">fundSchedule</a></h1>' ); //replace Tweets text at top
            ibody.find( '.p-name' ).css( 'color', '#07E0EB' ); //theme: tweets: links:
            }
            else {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
        }
        hideTwitterAttempts++;
        if ( hideTwitterAttempts < 3 ) {
            hideTwitterBoxElements();
        }
    }, 1500);
}

// somewhere in your code after html page load
hideTwitterBoxElements();
</script>
```

Image of change: http://img837.imageshack.us/img837/1139/btjc.png

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't directly answer CSS aspect of the question, but I think it's worth noting for completeness that some of what you want (eg hide borders / header) can be done using the data- attributes passed in the widget:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/twitterapi" 
    data-widget-id="YOUR-WIDGET-ID-HERE" 
    data-theme="dark"
    data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders noscrollbar transparent"
    data-link-color="#cc0000"
    width="200"
    height="300"
    >Tweets by @twitterapi</a>
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#customization

Maybe there's a performance benefit to minimising javascript arm wrestling where possible?

Answer (score 3):

They create an iframe, so it is another document.

You cannot style elements in another document, so it is not possible unless twitter provides a hook to embed your own stylesheet in their iframe..

Twitter only allows to style [the link color of the widget](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#customization) and pick a light/dark theme.

---

Alternatively, you can create your own widget by using the [twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) and then you can style it anyway you want..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it was possible back then when the question was asked, but now it is, check the [docs](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#options):

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-chrome="nofooter" ....">Tweets</a>
```

Comment: doh.. overlooked your answer before i posted - nice one

Answer (score 1):

It may be better to use twitters eventing structure.

as per https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading

```
<script>window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
  var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src= "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function (f) { t._e.push(f) } });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));</script>
```

and per https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events your event and hookup would look something like this (keep in mind this example uses jquery you can opt for a javascript only approach)

```
twttr.ready( function(twttr){
    twttr.events.bind("rendered", function(tw_event){
    var tw_iframe = ev.target;

    //the following is custom jquery code to do various 
    //css overrides based on selectors
    var twitterbody = $(tw_iframe).contents().find( 'body' );
       twitterbody.find(".avatar").hide();
       twitterbody.find("li.tweet").css({padding: "2px"});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As said above, you can't change CSS in a different origin iframe, here is some info:

[How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

http://www.jquery4u.com/dom-modification/jquery-change-css-iframe-content/

Comment: That's the point, you can't make changes the CSS of an external iframe. You can however create your own plugin using twitters api and then do what ever you wish with the CSS...

Comment: It's not a different domain though, twitter creates AND populates the iframe with js so the same origin policy doesn't apply.