# Chrome Extension Inject HTML on YouTube Page

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, google-chrome-extension, youtube

I am creating a Chrome Extension that will inject HTML on top of the related videos bar of a YouTube video.

[This is the desired effect of the plugin.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOiWL.jpg)

Here is the `manifest.json`:

```
{
  // Required
  "manifest_version": 2,

  // App
  "name": "...",
  "version": "...",
  "author": "...",
  "description": "...",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "run_at": "document_idle",
      "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/watch?v=*"],
      "js": ["jquery-min-3.3.1.js", "inject.js"]
    }
  ]

}
```

And here is `inject.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#related').prepend('<h1>This was injected throught jQuery.</h1>');
});
```

When the extension is loaded into Chrome and a YouTube video page is loaded, the script seems to work for a second. **The `h1` in injected at the top of the `#related` bar until related video thumbnails start to load**. Then the injected `h1` quickly is pushed to the bottom as each new thumbnail loads.

I'm guessing this has something to do with YouTube using AJAX to load content. Is there a way to wait until all AJAX has been loaded before injecting HTML?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait until an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists) and [Make function wait until element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149431/make-function-wait-until-element-exists).

Comment: See also [How to detect page navigation on Youtube and modify HTML before page is rendered?](//stackoverflow.com/a/34100952)