# Javascript: Changing visibility by clicking on div child

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

Code works perfectly standalone, but not with the rest of the html. I think it's because it's having trouble finding the child element to click on.

Check: https://ironpatch.co/apps/customify/view/example/1823535693868?variant=14751668666412&domain=ironpatch.co

To test: Click on thumbnail photos on the bottom left.

```js
document.querySelector('[data-target="1"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
  toolbar.style.visibility = "hidden";
}, false);

document.querySelector('[data-target="0"]').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');
  toolbar.style.visibility = "visible";
}, false);
```

```html
<div class="editor_thumbnail">
  <ul id="side-switcher">
    <li class="thumb product-switch"><img data-target="0" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/09/Icon_1_%28set_basic%29.png" alt="" class="tooltip img_switcher img d_block tooltipstered"></li>
    <li class="thumb product-switch"><img data-target="1" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3d/Icon_2_blue.svg/1024px-Icon_2_blue.svg.png"></li>
  </ul>
</div>


<ul id="toolbar">
  <li id="tab-ref-add_image" class="tab-link" data-tab="add_image"><a href="#" class="show"><i class="material-icons">add_a_photo</i><span class="icon-text txtLang">Add Art</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-ref-add_text" class="tab-link" data-tab="add_text"><a href="#" class="show"><i class="material-icons">font_download</i><span class="icon-text txtLang">Add Text</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-ref-add_layer" class="tab-link" data-tab="view_layer"><a href="#" class="show"><i class="material-icons">layers</i><span class="icon-text txtLang">Layers</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-ref-save_data" class="tab-link" data-tab="save_data"><a href="#" class="show"><i class="material-icons">save</i><span class="icon-text txtLang">Save Product</span></a></li>
  <li id="tab-ref-load_saved" class="tab-link" data-tab="load_saved"><a href="#" class="show"><i class="material-icons">assignment_turned_in</i><span class="icon-text txtLang">Load</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The white icons in the dark grey toolbar should hide and not work when the brown label thumbnail is clicked.

The white icons in the dark grey toolbar should show and work when the white shirt thumbnail is clicked.

Comment: I think the problem you're having is this javascript is being run before the page has fully loaded, so the thumbnails you're trying to select aren't there yet.

Comment: @dave morrissey I see. How would I work around this? The script is placed at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Have a look at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149431/make-function-wait-until-element-exists

Comment: Did you know ? The link you shared has a problem parsing `https://ironpatch.co/apps/customify/view/example/hidetoolbar.js`. The above javascript click events when executed indivudially on the console works fine.

Comment: @Panther do you know how i'd work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a child selector, like this:

```
// cache the toolbar
const toolbar = document.getElementById('toolbar');

// select the children elements (in this case elements with a class of ".child")
[...document.querySelectorAll("div > .child")].forEach((child) => {
  // add a click event listener to the child
  child.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // change the toolbar's visibility
    const visible = (toolbar.style.visibility === "visible");
    toolbar.style.visibility = visible ? "hidden" : "visible";
  });
});
```

**NOTE:** cache the `toolbar` variable ***outside*** of the `forEach` loop and/or event listener.

Good luck.

Comment: Tested but it didn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: It doesn't do anything because you need to change `"div > .child"` to match the selector of your child elements.

Comment: Not sure if i'm doing it right. I tried this ("#side-switcher > li") and ("#side-switcher > .thumb")

Comment: Try using `"#side-switcher img"` instead, let me know if it doesn't work.