# How to load javascript files after swagger UI is loaded in .net core web api project

Tags: javascript, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-2.2

I have a `web api project in .net core 2.2`,

I've integrated `swagger UI` to this project and as per my requirement I need to do some java script validations for Username and password,
So I configured java script in `startup.cs` as below:

```
`app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
 {
   c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Mobile Insurance API");
   c.InjectJavascript("basic-auth-swagger.js");
   c.InjectJavascript("sha256.js");
   c.InjectJavascript("Base64.js");
});
```

The problem I am facing here is, the below `javascript` files are loading before `swagger UI` is loaded due to this I am unable to find `javascript` and perform validations as per my requirement.

So is there any way to load `javascript` after `swagger UI` is loaded.
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to do this from here [Make function wait until element exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149431/make-function-wait-until-element-exists)

not sure if this is the best way but it works

```
// It takes the document a sec to load the swagger stuff loop until we find it
var checkExist = setInterval(function () {
    if (document.getElementById("swagger-ui") != null) {
        clearInterval(checkExist);

        // Add this method with your code
        DoSomethingWithElements();
    }
}, 100); // check every 100ms
```

Comment: on further investigation the "swagger-ui" ID is loaded before the rest of the page, I changed my code to find an element by ID I know I have "operations-tag-User", you will need to change that to an element on your page. and be careful if you rename it the original code will keep looping until the page is closed

Comment: For the given circumstances. It is not a wrong solution. Little dirty but functional. I targeted .information-container.