# check whether element is visible using intersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In my next.js component layout I am trying to check when a modal window that contains the div #snipcart is on visible in the window.

I am trying to use the IntersectionObserver to check this but I'm not getting an output?

How can I check when `div #snipcart` on screen in my app?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const cartTotal = document.querySelector('#cartTotal') !== null ? document.querySelector('#cartTotal').textContent.replace('£','') : ''
    const cartInvoiceNo = document.querySelector('#invoiceNo') !== null ? document.querySelector('#invoiceNo').textContent : ''
    
    if ((cartTotal &&!cartTotal.includes('}}')) && (cartInvoiceNo && !cartInvoiceNo.includes('}}'))) {
      setTagTotal(cartTotal)
      setTagInvoiceNo(cartInvoiceNo)
    }   

    let message = document.querySelector('#layout');

// INTERSECTION OBSERVER STUFF
const io = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
   if(entries[0].isIntersecting) {
    console.log(entries);
  }
}, {
    threshold: [0]
});

// ELEMENTS TO OBSERVE
const blk1 = document.querySelector('#snipcart');

// START OBSERVING ELEMENTS
io.observe(blk1);
```

Comment: You could try checking all the entries instead of just the first one? i.e. change `if(entries[0].isIntersecting) { console.log(entries) }` to `entries.forEach(entry => { console.log(entry); }`

Comment: thanks, I now get intersecting: false, I believe it should return true as my layout component is covering the whole window and the `#snipcart' div is within this window, is a threshold of 0 correct?

Comment: thanks, this seems to work, however I would like to check for a div that doesn't exist until it's loaded and I get the error Failed to execute 'observe' on 'IntersectionObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'., how can I prevent this error by checking if the element exists first?

Comment: Glad it works, threshold 0 means that as soon as they start intersecting. You can just do `if(element) { io.observe(element); }` or you could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35211286/3688864) and wait for the element to load.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code so that it checks if any of the entries are intersecting instead of just the first one, i.e. change

```
if(entries[0].isIntersecting) 
{ 
    console.log(entries);
}
```

to

```
entries.forEach(entry => 
{ 
    console.log(entry);
});
```

---

You currently have `threshold: [0]` which means

> The default is 0 (meaning as soon as even one pixel is visible, the callback will be run).

as explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

---

You should also check your element exists before observing.

```
if(element)
{
    io.observe(element);
}
```

or if you don't know when the element is going to exist, you can use the `MutationObserver` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16149431/make-function-wait-until-element-exists/35211286#35211286).