# How to wait for div to load before calling another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
var href;

    $(function(){
        $("a.load").click(function (e) { 
            e.preventDefault();
            href = this;

            // cover all bookmarks
            $("."+($(this).attr("class"))).css('border-bottom', 'solid 1px black');
            $("."+($(this).attr("class"))).css('background-color', '#F5F5F5');

            // uncover chosen bookmark
            $("#"+($(this).attr("id"))).css('border-bottom', 'solid 2px white');
            $("#"+($(this).attr("id"))).css('background-color', 'white');

            $("#tempMain").load($(this).attr("href")); // load content to temp div

            setTimeout(function() {resizeDivs();}, 500); // synchronize size of #main and #rightColumn
        });

    });

    function resizeDivs() {
        var heightNew = $("#tempMain").css("height");
        $("#rightColumn").css('height',heightNew);
        $("#main").css('height',heightNew);
        // $('#main').load($(href).attr('href'));
        $("#main").html($("#tempMain").html()); // is faster than loading again
    }
</script>
```

I'm loading subpages to a selected div of my main page by a jQuery function. In order to synchronise main div's and right column's height I'm using jQuery's `.css()` method. I wanted that resizing to look smoothly, so I've resolved it to following steps:
1. Load content of a subpage to an invisible temp div.
2. Calculate the height of that temp div.
3. Change the height of main div and right column to the height of that temp div.
4. Load content of a subpage to main div.

However, I am aware that my current way of doing this is pretty lame because of using `setTimeout()` as an improvisation of waiting for content to load - I've tried using `$(document).ready` but with no luck. Using a global variable (`var href`) also doesn't seem lege artis, but passing `this` operator of `$("a.load").click` function by `apply()` didn't work either.

How to do it "the right" way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait until an element exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists)

Comment: please update the correct answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use load callback

```
$("#tempMain").load($(this).attr("href"),function(){
   resizeDivs();
   // do other stuff load is completed
});
```

Comment: This will not work on local files (file://) -- modern JS blocks local file href's for security reasons.

Answer (score 32):

**with jquery**

```
function waitForElement(elementPath, callBack){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    if($(elementPath).length){
      callBack(elementPath, $(elementPath));
    }else{
      waitForElement(elementPath, callBack);
    }
  },500)
}
```

e.g. to use:

```
waitForElement("#myDiv",function(){
    console.log("done");
});
```

**here is without jquery**

```
function waitForElement(elementId, callBack){
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    if(element){
      callBack(elementId, element);
    }else{
      waitForElement(elementId, callBack);
    }
  },500)
}
```

e.g. to use:

```
waitForElement("yourId",function(){
    console.log("done");
});
```

Comment: This works on local files (file://), where jQuery's .load() callback does not.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a callback in the jQuery `load` function :

```
$("#tempMain").load($(this).attr("href"), resizeDivs);
```

see : http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

a simple script that i use to check if a (dynamic) DIV is loaded:

```
var tid = setInterval(timer, 100);

function timer() {

     var elementExist = $('#DIV');

     if (elementExist.length == 1) {

           functionToLoad();
     }
}

function functionToLoad(){

  clearInterval(tid);

  // REST OF CODE

}
```