# Set input values when jquery load() finishes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having problems setting an input after a jquery load finishes. I've tried the following posts on this site, and have had no success.

- [How to wait for div to load before calling another function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791479/how-to-wait-for-div-to-load-before-calling-another-function)
- [How to wait until an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists)
- [Do something AFTER the page has loaded completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9036969/do-something-after-the-page-has-loaded-completely)

No matter what I do, I get the following error "Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference" because the input hasn't loaded by the time setValues is called.

Below is a simplified version of my code (with some things I've tried commented out). I'm running it in IE11 standards mode (no compatability view). Any guidance/help is appreciated. **Basically, how do I wait until the inputs are loaded to call setValues?**:

frame1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<input name="input1" id="input1" />
<input name="input2"  id="input2" />
</body>
</html>
```

parentFrame.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> </script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="div1" style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px black solid;"> </div>
<div id="div2"> </div>
</body>
<script defer>
function setValues() {
    window.document.getElementById("input1").value="TEST";
    window.document.getElementById("input2").value="TEST";
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    //$("#div1").load("frame1.html", setValues);
    $("#div1").load("frame1.html");
});

$(window).load(setValues);

//document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", setValues, false )
/*
$("div").ready(function(){
    window.document.getElementById("input1").value="TEST";
    window.document.getElementById("input2").value="TEST";
});
*/

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: .load() takes an optional callback function. Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: `defer` is for external scripts only and should be used only when the `src=` attribute is present in `<script>`.

Comment: Try replacing your "frame1.html" file's content with nothing but the <input> tags (remove all headers, wrappers... anything except those 2 lines)

Comment: I tried that @Amit, and I still get the error.

Comment: ...you can create setInterval function which keeps going/checking for the inputs, once that returns true/we, you call setValues and remove the interval..

Comment: Then use a debugger and see what's not working. This way it's a guessing game

Comment: @jaakoj this was useful. Once I used setInterval and viewed in the console I kept seeing the same error over and over.

Basically the frame wasn't getting added to the DOM because load requires a webserver. I had this example on my local PC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not use the callback functionality of the first topic you have posted.

```
function setValues() {
    window.document.getElementById("input1").value="TEST";
    window.document.getElementById("input2").value="TEST";
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#div1").load("frame1.html", function(){
        setValues();
        //do more stuff after load
    });
});
```

Some Notes:

```
$(window).load(setValues);
```

This function is called right after `$(document).ready()` and therefore it is probably triggered before your `load()` event on `#div1`. You have to remove this line.

Moreover you should not load an element with the whole html skeleton again, but just the elements within the body.

`setValues()` should use jQuery functions too, when you have initialized it anyway.

**Edit:**

If you do not even see the loaded content the error occurs when trying to use `load()`. It will return an error when you try to get a html file without a webserver. (c:/path/file.html).

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/path/frame1.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

I guess you will have the same problem. It occurs because you do not use a web server (you request your file through a file path rather than a domain/localhost). You must use **http requests**. Using a server such as **apache** (or bundled in xampp) will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hosch, but I still get the error. Please re-read my question I've tried the callback function already.

Comment: have you removed the $(window).load() function while trying this? It occurs before and will stop js from running.

Comment: I have. It's basically as you suggested in your post and still the error occurs.

Comment: I think the problem occurs when using load(). I edited my post.

Comment: Thanks Hosch! I made this example on my desktop. Once I used a webserver it worked perfectly!

Comment: glad this helped you. consider upvoting it, when you actually accepted it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82980/discussion-between-jon-and-hosch-nok).