# Getting coordinates of a DIV tag

Tags: jquery

enter code hereIf you look at this code it gets the left coordinate of the div tag - http://jsfiddle.net/JuPA4/3/ which is pretty much what I need.

```
$(function () {
    var position = $("#red11").offset();
    $("#amount").val(position.left);
});
```

(I have asked on the Hype forums and have had no answer for 3 days now)

> Console error is (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'left' of
>   undefined) not sure why as I can interact with the element!

The black dot element is within a div tag called `#black` for some reason the code posted above does not work with the `hype` file! I know I can interact with it and I have added a demonstration to the page click Hide / Show to interact with the dot.

I am not the best with Javascript so if anybody has any ideas then the help would be appreciated.

The end result of this is that the coordinates for both left and top are updated to a text input so I can place them into a database.

Comment: This works fine in Chrome for me. What browser?  The other possibility is that it executes too early?  Meaning before the dom is finished drawing.

Comment: What is *Hype*? What *black dot element*? *Click Hide / Show* where? There seems to be a lot of information missing from your question

Comment: You need to produce code that fails in the way that it does on "Hype" in a jsfiddle example or tag this as "hype" and "jquery" in order to get help from someone who knows "Hype" and can help you figure out what you need to do, or how to explain the problem better here.

Comment: [Tumult Hype](http://tumult.com/hype/) appears to be some kind of IDE or code generator. Not really a candidate for a SO tag.

Comment: Sorry wrong link posted, this is the one you need - http://jsfiddle.net/JuPA4/3/

Hype is a html5 animation script for Mac, just a code generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `.offset()` on a selector that does not match any elements, it returns `undefined`, and it appears that your selector is executed before the "black" element is added to the DOM. You need to delay your code until after the element is added to the DOM.

You can check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists) for a solution. It shows a way to watch the DOM.

Or you could try something like the following, which just tries, waits, and tries again until the element is there:

```
<script>
function executeWhenExists(selector, wait, callback) {
    if ($(selector).length > 0) {
        callback();
    } else {
        setTimeout(function() { executeWhenExists(selector, wait, callback) }, wait);
    }
}

$(function () {
    executeWhenExists("#black", 1000, function() {
        var position = $("#black").offset();
        $("#amount").val(position.left);
    });
});
</script>
```

It might even be sufficient to delay your code until the window's load event (rather than have it run in the document's ready event). That would look like this:

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function () {
    var position = $("#black").offset();
    $("#amount").val(position.left);
});
</script>
```

Comment: That done the job but the coordinates do not update now when you move the black dot which means there must be something from the hype side of the javascript interfering with it, I think my solution is to just drop Hype as it is not well supported and do it all in html 5 and css3 myself.

Thanks for your help John, much appreciated.

Comment: I went back to the code this morning and solved it within a few minutes by calling the function upon a button click, so not updating live like the original javascript but it is a reasonable work around.