# Chrome extension: must delay page load until javascript finishes

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, delay

My extension reformats an ugly page that I visit often. Currently, the page first loads un-fixed, then there is a ~100ms delay, then my JS formats the html.

How do I prevent the uncorrected html from ever displaying?

My JS file is defined in the manifest as follows:

```
,"content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["*://*.<url goes here>.com/*"],
        "js": ["js/1.js"]
}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to adjust the [`run_at` parameter](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at).

By default, content scripts are executed after the page is fully loaded (at `"document_idle"`).

Try adding `"document_end"` first and see if it improves the delay.

> In the case of `"document_end"`, the files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded.

```
"content_scripts": [{
  "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"],
  "js": ["js/1.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
}]
```

This may still be too late. There's a final option, `"document_start"`, that you can use, but beware - it executes *really* early, before any of the DOM is ready. There's nothing yet for you to correct.

You can [wait for an element to appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists) and correct it immediately though, for instance.

You may also try to correct things with CSS injection. This can be safely inserted at `"document_start"` with no extra tricks.

P.S. Or, for example, use Gael's answer - add a CSS rule to hide the body, wait until the page is loaded (for instance, with `DOMContentLoaded` event), correcting it and then removing/overriding the CSS rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can set run_at: "document_start" in your manifest. Add a rule to hide the page, and differ your current script in a window.onload event.

If you are visiting often this page, you could even load first your template/redesign, and then integrate the page data that you want from a cache or from the source.

Comment: The idea to hide the page, modify and then remove the rule is very good.