# Creating extension chrome content which injects script on the page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension that puts a content into the websites accessed by the user.
But I'm having a problem! I did the extent and i sent to the "webstore", and when I do the installation of the extension, it does not put the content on the websites that I access.
I want to know, what am I doing wrong in the code?

manifest.json

```
{
  "content_scripts": [ {
      "all_frames": true,
      "js": ["background.js"],

    "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "<all_urls>" ],

    "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "description": "Injeta anuncios em site de terceiros.",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Vi Anúncios",
  "permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "management",
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking"
  ],
  "version": "1.4",
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    "background.js"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.innerHTML = "<p>testando</p>";

document.body.insertBefore (div, document.body.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

[At `"document_start"`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at), `document.body` **does not exist yet!**

You are running the script too early, before any of the DOM is constructed.

You may want to move this to `"document_end"` or `"document_idle"`, or [otherwise wait for the DOM to be constructed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded). You could also [wait for a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists) with Mutation Observers.

---

Unrelated advice: do not call your content script `background.js`. This is *not* a background script, and this will inevitably lead to confusion.