# How to trigger Chrome Extension function based on page's content?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I wrote an extension for a website that is based on the data on the page. I've been testing my function so far by pressing a browser action icon to test. However, I'm trying to make it so the changes on the page trigger it to automatically fire.

How do I listen for content changing on the website in order to fire my function? The content is being changed through javascript on the site.

Comment: If you know what a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) is then you can use `MutationObserver` or `setInterval`-based polling: [How to wait until an element exists?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5525071)

Comment: Nice second dupe link, wOxxOm, but that question just takes seniority.