# Jasmine test method executed when Meteor template is rendered

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor, jasmine, client-side

I am writing unit tests in Jasmine+Velocity for a Meteor application. On the client side, some methods are being executed to set classes for HTML divs when a template is rendered. For example:

```
Template.text.rendered = function () {

  Meteor.call("textCheck", function (err, status) {

    var pageState       = $('#pageState');

    if (status.text.success){
      pageState.addClass('text-success');
    }else{
      pageState.addClass('text-danger');
    }
};
```

My problem is I don't know how to call the function when the text template is rendered through Jasmine. I searched a lot of documentation online but could not find any information on how to call `Template.rendered` in a Jasmine test. `I am using sanjo-jasmine.` Also I can't understand how to check in my test if the class has been added to the div or not. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to these functions:

```
/**
 * Call the function f the first time the template will be rendered
 * And then remove the function inserted
 * @param {Template} template A meteor template
 * @param {callback} f The function to execute after the template has been rendered
 */
this.afterRendered = function(template, f) {

    // Insert our rendered function
    template._callbacks.rendered.push(function() {
        template._callbacks.rendered.pop();
        f();
    });
}


/**
 * @source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists
 * @brief Wait for something to be ready before triggering a timeout
 * @param {callback} isready Function which returns true when the thing we're waiting for has happened
 * @param {callback} success Function to call when the thing is ready
 * @param {callback} error Function to call if we time out before the event becomes ready
 * @param {int} count Number of times to retry the timeout (default 300 or 6s)
 * @param {int} interval Number of milliseconds to wait between attempts (default 20ms)
 */
this.waitUntil = function (isready, success, error, count, interval) {
    if (count === undefined) {
        count = 300;
    }
    if (interval === undefined) {
        interval = 20;
    }
    if (isready()) {
        success();
        return;
    }
    // The call back isn't ready. We need to wait for it
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!count) {
            // We have run out of retries
            if (error !== undefined) {
                error();
            }
        } else {
            // Try again
            waitUntil(isready, success, error, count -1, interval);
        }
    }, interval);
}
```

They are perfectly doing the job with Mocha + Velocity. With Mocha, you just need to create a file `lib.js` anywhere in the `tests/mocha/client` folder and paste it.

Mocha example (sorry I do not use jasmine):

```
describe("check something", function() {
    it ("test something", function(done) {
        afterRendered(Template.homepage, function() {
            chai.expect(...).to.not.be.undefined;
            done();
        });
        FlowRouter.go('somewhere');
    });

    it ("test something else", function(done) {
        FlowRouter.go('home');
        var waitUntilOnError = function(done) {
            return function() {
                done("Failed to wait until")
            }
        };
        var test = function() {
            return $('div').length === 1;
        }
        var maxAttempt = 200;
        var waitBetweenAttempt = 60;
        this.timeout(maxAttempt * waitBetweenAttempt * 2);
        waitUntil(test, done, waitUntilOnError, maxAttempt, waitBetweenAttempt);
    });
});
```