# How to loop check for a button in Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am interested in waiting until a button is active in a webbrowser. I don't know whether to do maybe a while, a loop reload or a loop check or whatever.

The focus is no matter what, I need to have the fastest and most reliable way to check for a button **as soon** as it is available.

Here is the html:

```
<p>
<input class="btn add-to-cart pull-left" name="add" id="add" value="Add to Cart" type="submit">   
</p>
```

Thank you!

Comment: See also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists .

Comment: Guys, this isn't a duplicate...