# Javascript cannot getElementById

Tags: javascript

I've got a site which has annoying features - f.e it detects adblock and puts on big rectangle on the video window saying that I should disable adblock. The code for this looks like this:

```
<div class="tvpoverlay_element" id="tvpoverlay_abdinfo" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div style="top: 20%; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute; display: block; pointer-events: auto;">
```

So if I insert `display: none` in the second line, the rectangle would disappear, and I would be very happy. I wanted to make simple script to automate this process. I tried command:

`document.getElementById('tvpoverlay_abdinfo').style.display = 'none'`

but `.getElementById()` returrns null. How can I get to this div and change the display, if the solution above doesn't work?

Comment: Are you sure that the element already exists when you're trying to access it?

Comment: I am pretty new to javascript, what does it mean? :D

Comment: @FrynioS can you give us a fiddle?

Comment: Try the command `document.getElementById('tvpoverlay_abdinfo')` in the developer console of the site, and check it finds the element

Comment: If I can manually change it, then it prolly exists, but when I type this to the console, it doesn't work. And the command above returns null

Comment: @FrynioS Then check whether it's inside an iframe.

Comment: @JLRishe, yes it is in iframe

Comment: @FrynioS What happens if you hide the iframe?

Comment: I don;t know what do you mean by hiding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First check that when you are triggering that code line, the element exists (e.g. if the app is using Angular or react or whatever JS Framework, those elements don't exist at the beginning)

Maybe is a good solution for you write a script to check if the element exist and then execute your code ([How to wait until an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists))

The command is right, so just trigger it at the right moment.

If is inside an iframe, try this ([Javascript - Get element from within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/javascript-get-element-from-within-an-iframe))

Comment: It is in iframe, but it has no id :(

Comment: Is it the only iframe in the page?

Comment: You can include an Id to the iframe or search by class if is unique or getElementsByTag which returns an array and check another uniques attr to get your iframe