# Dialog that may or may not appear on page start

Tags: cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I need to handle the case where my page may display a popup dialog at the load stage, or it may not appear. Clicking anywhere will remove it and I'm not interested in testing this dialog, but it blocks the page I need to access so it must be removed

This is the code that will get the dialog when it appears

```js
cy.get('.wps_popup')
  .find('[data-wps-popup-close]')
  .click()
```

but I cannot put that at the top of the test, because this element might not appear.

How do I handle a conditional element - do I need to `intercept` DOM changes and put that code in the event listener?

Comment: Have you answered the question of what triggers the modal to appear? This may help you find an easier answer than polling for the element.

Comment: @jjhelguero. Yes indeed, it's a special offer coupon for first-time shoppers. Unless I try to hack the A/B testing mechanism which seems OTT, the best solution is the accepted one.

Comment: Sure, if you can somehow avoid that with an API call that would be better. I'm not sure how your app determines a first-time shopper.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for an element that may not exist using Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47773525/how-to-check-for-an-element-that-may-not-exist-using-cypress)

Comment: In general conditional assertions is an anti-pattern, it will be easier and more rebust to figure out how to dismiss the popup or prevent it from showing up. e.g. most of those popups set a cookie when they are being dismissed to avoid showing up in the same session.
If that's the case you can use https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/setcookie to set it yourself

Comment: Clearly it's ***not*** an anti-pattern, because the popup is not being tested.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't care about actually testing the dialog, you can add a listener at the top of the test.

```js
function handler(win) {
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
    const addedElement = mutations?[0].addedNodes?[0]
    if (addedElement?.classList.contains('wps_popup')) {
      addedElement.click()
    }
  }
  observer.observe(win.document.body, { childList: true })
}
cy.on('window:load', handler)
```

This will run independently of the Cypress test, but please note it responds to each and every change to the DOM.

To minimize the impact on test runner, turn it off as soon as possible

```js
it('tests with background handler', () => {

  function handler(win) {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      const addedElement = mutations?[0].addedNodes?[0]
      if (addedElement?.classList.contains('wps_popup')) {
        addedElement.click()
      }
    }
    observer.observe(win.document.body, { childList: true })
  }
  cy.on('window:load', handler)

  cy.visit('/')

  // some test code

  cy.off('window:load', handler)            // turn off 
})
```