# Unable to find the element to check if it exists in the before() hook in cypress.io

Tags: cypress, assertion, cypress-conditional-testing

I have the following lines of code in my **before()** hook.

```js
before(() ==> {
cy.get(this.testPopup).then(($el) => {
   if ($el.length) {
      cy.get(this.testPopupCloseButton).click();
      cy.get(this.testPopup).should("not.exist");
    } 
  });
});
```

There will be a popup which will display sometimes and sometimes it will not. I tried to write a logic to close that popup and check if it getting disappeared on closing only when the popup exists.

But I am getting the following error.

> Timed out retrying after 30000ms: Expected to find element: #test-popup-element, but never found it.
>
> Because this error occurred during a before all hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite`

I am expecting a soft assert here basically, which will continue to run the rest of the tests even if this assertion fails.

Please advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dialog that may or may not appear on page start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72960188/dialog-that-may-or-may-not-appear-on-page-start)

Answer (score 5):

You can't resolve the issue using `cy.get('body').then(($body) =>` because the code will finish before the popup appears. There is **no retry** in that code, it always decides **imediately** if the popup is present.

Instead, use **element polling** as shown by Fody here:
[How to check for an element that may not exist using Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76378213/16695029)

```js
const ifElementExists = (selector, attempt = 0) => {
  if (attempt === 100) return null           // no appearance, return null
  if (Cypress.$(selector).length === 0) {
    cy.wait(100, {log:false})                // wait in small chunks
    getDialog(selector, ++attempt)           // try again
  }
  return cy.get(selector, {log:false})       // done, exit with the element
}

// Wait for 10 seconds for the popup
ifElementExists(this.testPopup).then($el => {
  if ($el?.length) {
    cy.get(this.testPopupCloseButton).click()
    cy.get(this.testPopup).should('not.exist')
  }
})
```

This works because it will keep waiting for the popup up to 10 seconds.
Increase  `if (attempt === 100)` if you need longer waiting time. You have to decide the longest time you need to wait and set `attempt` limit accordingly.

If it never appears in that time, `if ($el?.length)` will be `false` and the close button won't be clicked.

Otherwise, the popup has eventually appeared and the code can go ahead and click the close button.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is that using `cy.get(this.testPopup)` contains [an implicit assertion](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress#Implicit-Assertions) that the `this.testPopup` element exists. So in the case where it doesn't, the test fails because Cypress can't find the element.

[From the Cypress Conditional Testing documentation,](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing#Element-existence) they recommend using `cy.get('body')` and then querying for the element ([using JQuery's `.find()`.](https://api.jquery.com/find/))

```js
before(() ==> {
  cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
    if ($body.find(this.testPopup).length) {
      cy.get(this.testPopupCloseButton).click();
      cy.get(this.testPopup).should("not.exist");
    } 
  });
});
```