# Is there a way to use 'exist' in a conditional statement in Cypress?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I need to check multiple pages for whether a list exists, and if so, get the length of the list. This works fine except some pages do not have lists (this is intentional). Is there any way I can use .should('exist') to check if the list is there and if so check it, otherwise just continue?

I currently have this test:

```js
if (cy.get('.mt-5').should('exist')) {
    cy.get('.mt-5')
        .find('li')
        .then(($listItems) => {
            const listLength = $listItems.length;
            cy.wrap(listLength).as('listLength');
        });
}
```

however, this just causes a timeout when it gets to the `if` statement as it is looking for `.mt-5` which does not always exist.

Answer (score 3):

The command `cy.get('.mt-5')` can't be used as a test in the `if()` statement, but you can try using `Cypress.$('.mt-5')` instead.

The problem will be that you loose the retry built in to `cy.get()`. It would be preferable not to use a conditional statement in the test, instead try to set up the test condition such that you always have that element.

```js
if (Cypress.$('.mt-5').length) {
    cy.get('.mt-5')
        .find('li')
        .then(($listItems) => {
            const listLength = $listItems.length;
            cy.wrap(listLength).as('listLength');
        });
}
```

If you really have to use conditional testing, and need to wait for the `.mt-5` element, there is a way to add your own retry via ***element polling***.

See [How to check for an element that may not exist using Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76378213/16695029)