# how to pass an assertion in if condition using cypress without halting the execution in case of assertion failure

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

I am trying to pass an assertion to if condition and execute a logic when the condition is met and another logic when condition is failed.

Since the test is failing on failure of assertion i am not able to achieve the desired result.

I tried the following...

```js
if(cy.get("div").length \> 0) {
  cy.log("print this")
} else {
  cy.log("print this")
}
```

or

```
if(cy.get("div").should('have.length.greaterThan', 0) {
  cy.log("print this")
} else {
  cy.log("print this")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, certain Cypress commands (inlcuding `cy.get()`) [contain *implicit* assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability#Implicit-Assertions) - meaning that Cypress will fail a test if the implicit assertion is not met. In this case, if `cy.get()` fails to find an element, that fails the implicit assertion, and the test will fail.

Additionally, Cypress commands will yield objects that are of type `Chainable<T>`, meaning they don't yield traditional objects that can have `.length` appended to them.

Instead of using `cy.get('div')`, we get the parent element and search for the `div` element using JQuery functions.

```js
cy.get('body') // get the parent of the div
  .then(($body) => { // then unwraps the Chainable<JQueryHTMLElement> Object
    if ($body.find('div').length) { // We can use JQuery commands directly on the yielded $body element
      // code if `div` has a length greater than 0
    } else {
      // code if `div` has a length of 0
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to check the result of a command without failing the test, add a `.should()` that returns `undefined`.

```js
cy.get('div#does-not-exist')
  .should(() => undefined)          // stops the above failing
  .then($result => {
    if ($result.length) {
      cy.log('Found')
    } else {
      cy.log('Not found')    
    }
  })
```

[image]

This works because `.should()` ***modifies the implicit assertion*** in the `cy.get()`.

For example, if you run `cy.get('div#does-not-exist').should('not.exist')` it will pass. The `not` in the should inverts (negates) the implicit assertion in the `cy.get()`.

The `.should(() => undefined)` also changes the implicit assertion, but allows you to perform the `if()` check further down the chain.

**Please note** all of the methods mentioned so far do not allow checking of elements that are in the process of loading, i.e there is no retry built in.

To do that, you need to **poll the element** as shown here
[How to check for an element that may not exist using Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76378213/18366749)

Answer (score 6):

To pass the assertion to `if()` change `cy.get()` to `Cypress.$()`.

```js
if(Cypress.$('div').length > 0) {
  cy.log("print this")
} else {
  cy.log("print that")
}
```

`cy.get()` is a wrapper around `Cypress.$()` that retries until timeout then fails.

`Cypress.$()` just returns a jQuery object which has `length === 0` if it fails, but in either case the test continues.

Make sure the page has finish loading (no fetch not yet responded) before running ***any*** `if()` condition.

Answer (score 3):

Use [cypress-if](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if) plugin.

```js
cy.get("div")
  .if()
  .log("if statement passed, do this")
  .else()
  .log("else statement passed, do that")
```

You will need this plugin because Javascript statements like `if(cy.get())` do not work with Cypress commands.

That is because Cypress put's it's commands onto a queue and runs independently of the statements in the javascript.

Adding the above plugin will give you access to `if()` statement ***inside the queue***, and will branch according to the result of the `cy.get("div")`.

When `cy.get("div")` does not find the element, it will not have an implicit assertion, instead it will pass the result to the next command sequence.

Answer (score 0):

try to use then((), it should help

```
cy.get("div").then(($div) => {
  if ($div.length > 0) {
    cy.log("print this")
  } else {
    cy.log("print this")
  }
})
```