# Chrome extension unable to select DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a Chrome extension that reacts to the clicking on a specific element on a page (example of this type of page: https://www.mentimeter.com/s/ea1639a1b16e623b9c7b4bc884f86aae/cc3aaa4bae22).

The specific element I really am interested in is a `<rect>` element, but for the sake of simplicity I provide this demo which shows that I can get the script to react to the clicking on a high-level `<div id="root">` element but not its child `<div class="application mm-ui">` (see listing of page elements in image).

[image: page elements shown by Chrome dev tools]

I would be grateful for any clue as to how I can select other elements lower down in the DOM. The jQuery code for selecting the `<div class="application mm-ui">` element works fine if I enter it into the javascript console in Chrome Dev Tools instead of using the extension.

The extension folder includes a downloaded copy of jQuery 3.3.1 (name: "jquery.js") in addition to the manifest.json and the content.js.

(I guess there is also a way to make the page download jQuery from googleapis but I haven't yet managed to find out how. One thing at a time.)

**manifest.json**

```
 {
  "manifest_version": 2, 
  "name": "Mentimeter demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Mentimeter demo",
 "content_scripts": [{
      "js": ["jquery.js","content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://www.mentimeter.com/*"]
  }]
}
```

**content.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("div#root").click(function(){//works
$("div.application").click(function(){//does not work
alert("click");
});
});
```

***Wait. There's more.***

The puzzling thing is that a simpler version using vanilla JS manages to select the `<rect>` elements without problem:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Vanilla JS selection demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Vanilla JS selection demo",

  "content_scripts": [{
    "js": ["content.js"],
    "matches": ["https://www.mentimeter.com/*"]
  }]
```

**content.js**

```
document.addEventListener("click",function(event){
var target = event.target;
if(target.tagName.toLowerCase() == "rect"){
alert("rect clicked");
} 
},false);
```

Comment: Can't remember what it exactly was, but Chrome extensions I think might not run inside a space where `document` is defined. Maybe not even `window`? I would suggest Googling how to edit the document from within a Chrome extension. (If you want to be sure, run a `console.log(window, document);` and see what's available)

Comment: Could it be that the DOM node in question is added after the initial document is parsed (from a script)? Then `$(document).ready()` is too early and you'll have to [watch for the node being added](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525071/934239).

Comment: @NirajKaushal Incorrect; it's a separate content script JS context.

Comment: The typical solution is to use event delegation: $(document).on('click', 'div.application', function() { ...... })

Comment: And if you don't want to use event delegation you can consider using this excellent library http://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive

Comment: @minitauros: I forgot to mention that I already have an extension using vanilla JS where selection of the `<rect>`element works. I have edited my post accordingly. I need jQuery to make a more advanced version of the actual extension (these are just demos).

Comment: @danbae your working code basically does the same as event delegation in jQuery.

Comment: @Xan: if you are right about the delay, why does the vanilla JS (added to my post above) work?

Comment: why does the vanilla JS work? Because as @wOxxOm said its using event delegation.

Comment: @elegant-user: please help me understand how I should modify my jQuery code such that it works like the vanilla JS. Complete sentences are appreciated – I'm no expert as I'm sure you have noticed already.

Comment: Use what @wOxxOm has suggested `$(document).on('click', 'div.application', function() { ...... })` or use this easy to use `mutationObserver` library http://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive if you don;t want to use event delegation.

Comment: @elegant-user and wOxxOm: Thanks a lot... I'm a bit slow, sorry about that. It works now. Please feel free to create an answer and take credit for solving this.
`$(document).on("click","rect",function(){alert("click");});`

Comment: @elegant-user It works, because [events bubble](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture).

Comment: Quick vanillaJS tip: instead of checking `target.tagName.toLowerCase()`, you can also issue a `if (target instanceof HTMLRectElement) {}` (you would have to look up if the element is indeed a `HTMLRectElement`, but this is how this usually works).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

Use what @wOxxOm has suggested use jQuery event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', 'rect', function() { ...... })
```

or use this easy to use mutationObserver library [github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive](http://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive) if you don't want to use event delegation.