# How to wait until an element exists with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise

I'm working with a `proxy object` where I detect a object value change and then load new content via AJAX, I use a `setInterval` function to wait until a the element that comes in the AJAX request exist and then execute a piece of code. I'm doing in this way because my case requires it. I made a short snippet example:

```js
var handler = {
    makeThings: 0,
    otherStuff: 0
};
var globalHandler = new Proxy(handler, {
    set: function(obj, prop, value) {
        obj[prop] = value
        if (prop == "makeThings") {
            var clearTimeSearchProxy = setInterval(function() {
                if ($("p").length) {
                    console.log("The element finally exist and we execute code");
                    clearTimeout(clearTimeSearchProxy);
                }
            }, 100);
        }
        return true;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        globalHandler.makeThings = 1;
        //This element comes with ajax but I use a setTimeout for this example
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#newContent").append("<p>Ajax element</p>");
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button>New content</button>
  <div id="newContent"></div>
</body>
```

Now I'm wondering about how to improve the code in a cleaner, efficient and elegant way. I was thinking of using `promises` instead of `setInterval` to execute a code when the element that comes via AJAX exists in the `DOM`.

How can I make it work? Should I use other JavaScript functionality for this case instead of `promises`? I'm stuck with the promise to achieve what I need, this what I have tried so far.

```js
var handler = {
    makeThings: 0,
    otherStuff: 0
};
var globalHandler = new Proxy(handler, {
    set: function(obj, prop, value) {
        obj[prop] = value
        if (prop == "makeThings") {
            var myFirstPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if ($("p").length) {
                    resolve("Exist");
                } else {
                    reject("It doesnt exist.");
                }
            });

            myFirstPromise.then((data) => {
                console.log("Done " + data);
            }).catch((reason) => {
                console.log("Handle rejected promise: " + reason);
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        globalHandler.makeThings = 1;
        //This element comes with ajax but I use a setTimeout for this example
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#newContent").append("<p>Ajax element</p>");
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button>New content</button>
  <div id="newContent"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to wait until an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally made it with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)`interface` in an easy way instead of with `promises`.

```js
var handler = {
    makeThings: 0,
    otherStuff: 0
};
var globalHandler = new Proxy(handler, {
    set: function(obj, prop, value) {
        obj[prop] = value
        if (prop == "makeThings") {
            var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                if ($("p").length) {
                    console.log("Exist, lets do something");
                    observer.disconnect();
                }
            });
            // start observing
            observer.observe(document.body, {
                childList: true,
                subtree: true
            });
        }
        return true;
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        $("p").remove();
        globalHandler.makeThings = 1;
        //This element comes with ajax but I use a setTimeout for this example
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#newContent").append("<p>Ajax element</p>");
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <button>New content</button>
  <div id="newContent"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: If someone need a very simple and readable example of MutationObserver you can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57395241/6542186

Answer (score 5):

Do not ***wait***. Rather subscribe for notification of a change in the target element.

The API to utilise for listening to changes in the DOM tree is the [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

> The MutationObserver interface provides the ability to watch for changes being made to the DOM tree. It is designed as a replacement for the older Mutation Events feature which was part of the DOM3 Events specification.

Use it to observe change in an element as follows:

```
// You selected `$("p")` in your snippet, suggesting you're watching for the inclusion of 'any' `p` element.
// Therefore we'll watch the `body` element in this example
const targetNode = document.body;

// Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)
const config = {
    attributes: false,
    characterData: false,
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
};

// Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
const callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {
    for(let mutation of mutationsList) {

        if ( mutation.type === "childList" ) {
            continue;
        }

        const addedNodes = Array.from( mutation.addedNodes) ;

        if ( addedNodes && addedNodes.some( node => node.nodeName === "P" ) ) {
            observer.disconnect();

            console.log("The element finally exist and we execute code");
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to set 'childList' to true in the config and then skip that mutation type in the observer callback?

Comment: If you're indeed convinced that the `config` is strictly set up for observation of child addition/removal then you ought not check the mutation type.

Answer (score 1):

[rxjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs) can highly simplify what you are trying to do. A very basic implementation, using only a Subject and subscription:

```js
const {
  Subject
} = rxjs;

const sub = new Subject();

sub.subscribe(e => {
  console.log(`received data ${e}`);
  // do your thing
});

// simulate something async
setTimeout(() => {
  sub.next('foo');
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.5.2/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```