# Target _blank not being added to HTML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to manipulate the DOM using jQuery. In my website, a header is being imported by a widget. I cannot edit this code directly, but a specific anchor in the header should have target _blank. When doing this, nothing happens. I get no error in my console, and nothing changes in the DOM.

I've used this jQuery code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#iwgh2-navigation-menu-toggle-animation-wrapper a').attr('target', '_blank');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="iwgh2-navigation-menu-site" style="" href="http://binnenland.vlaanderen.be">Anchor Text</a>
```

What I have checked:

- The code is being executed. When I deliberately write a syntax error, I get an error in my console.
- I tried to change the code to use .remove() instead of adding the anchor, but nothing happened as well.

Comment: If you get an error, then please tell us what it is

Comment: Assuming that the anchor has a parent element with id `iwgh2-navigation-menu-toggle-animation-wrapper` [your code works](https://jsfiddle.net/jbxw8znk/).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vyfp6c75/ -- this works for me, using `.attr()` and `.prop()`

Comment: Just change to: `jQuery('.iwgh2-navigation-menu-site').attr('target', '_blank');`

Comment: @Andy Yes, it does. But the code doesn't do anything.

Comment: You say the header is imported by a widget. Is that an ajax request? If you're waiting for an element to become available after an ajax request [you might find this useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13709125/1377002).

Comment: @Andy Thank you so much. That might be the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The id you use in your JS-code is not present in your HTML. 
Add it there and your code will work:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('#iwgh2-navigation-menu-toggle-animation-wrapper a').attr('target', '_blank');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="iwgh2-navigation-menu-toggle-animation-wrapper">
  <a class="iwgh2-navigation-menu-site" style="" href="http://binnenland.vlaanderen.be">Anchor Text</a>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can also just use 
`jQuery('.iwgh2-navigation-menu-site').attr('target', '_blank');`
to add the attribute to every link with the classname.

Comment: `jQuery('.iwgh2-navigation-menu-toggle-animation-wrapper a')` would not work, since there is no class with that name

Comment: you are right, i forgot to delete the `a` from the selector. Thank you!

Comment: No its not the a, there is no class called `iwgh2-navigation-menu-toggle-animation-wrapper`

Comment: Thank's again, now it should be correct  copy-pasting is hard. :D

Answer (score -1):

Try using this instead:
    `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.iwgh2-navigation-menu-site').attr('target', '_blank');
    });`

I can only assume that the parent element id does not match your selector operator.

Comment: This does not work as well. I'm still getting no error in the console either. Any other thoughts that might help?

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I'm getting shown no error at all.

Comment: test that your jquery is actually functioning by running this:
jQuery('body').hide()

Comment: not really sure why my answer has been downvoted as it has a valid answer? Can someone please shed some light upon this?