# Access DOM elements from within setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am javascript/jquery noobie. Trying to hack together something for personal project
How to access elements using jquery from within setTimeout.
I am trying to click a button after three seconds and I tried the following
Eg

`setTimeout((){$("#id1").click()}, 3000)`
However I am not able to access any element from within the setTimeout. I have to hold reference to the element outside and then click.

```
var ele = $("#id1");
setTimeout((){ele.click()}, 3000)
```

How can I acces elements from within a `setTimeout` or `setInterval`

**EDIT**:
I do not have access to all the div elemets and cannot store in a variable or attach it to a timeout
I have to click a button after 3 seconds. Another button will be available after I click this. The second button is not hidden but simple not available. So I need something like this

```
$("#id1").click();
    setTimeout((){
    $("#id2").click();
    }, 3000);
}, 3000)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [this](https://gist.github.com/PizzaBrandon/5709010) mentioned in the [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists) answer to satisfy my use case

Answer (score 0):

you could use `.bind(null,somethinWithDom)` in the callbackFunction
and now the function has a new parameter `(somethingWithDomBinded) => {}`

But for practical uses you need to use Event listeners, instead passing you domThing you could trigger an event in the callback then listen and trigger whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

First you have syntax error in you code

ur Html

```
<button id="id1">Click</button>
```

ur jQuery

```
setTimeout(() => {
    var ele = $("#id1");
    ele.click(() => {
      console.log(ele.html())
    })
  }, 3000);
```

Inside click You have to call another func and you can put your logic there

Comment: $("#id1") is undefined when I try it from within the setTimout

Comment: Did u try my code isn't it working?   Because the $("#id1") inside the setTimeout () function  and it's working perfectly

Comment: I have the button available only after 3 seconds. var ele = $("#id1"); executes first

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing the **Arrow operator =>**. Check this out:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(() =>{
   console.log($("#id1"));
 }, 3000);
});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="id1">Click me</button>
```

Or you can just access it like this:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log($("#id1")), 3000);
```