# get element when it appears

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, settimeout

there is one element on webpage I need to get, it usually takes some time to appear, so I googled out such solution which meets my requirement
in [How to wait until an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists)

```
function getElement(selector, i = 5) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        if (i <= 0) return reject(`${selector} not found`);
        const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        if (elements.length) return resolve(elements);
        return setTimeout(async () => await getElement(selector, i - 1), 1000);
    })
}

// Now call it with your selector

try {
    element = await getElement('.woohoo');
} catch (e) {
  // catch the e 
}

//OR

getElement('.woohoo', 5)
.then(element => {
  // do somthing with the elements 
})
.catch(e => { 
  // catch the error 
});
```

I have tested in my project, it will return the element if the target element is there at the beginning, but will report '**Uncaught (in promise) XX not found**' error if the target element never appears, the worst case is nothing returns if the target element appears after trying times between 4 and 1, no exception, no element

what's wrong with the code? or how to fix it?

thanks.

Comment: [That answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61640061/1048572) has the most horrible code from all the answers on that page. Why not choose [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61511955/1048572) instead?

Comment: @Bergi  thanks, "Why not choose [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists/61511955#61511955) instead?" It does not handle the failed case, for instance, I will only wait 5 seconds, if the target does not appear, I will print "error", for [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists/61640061#61640061), I just remove 'async', seems not working, how to make it work?

Comment: Just add a `const timer = setTimeout(() => { observer.disconnect(); reject(new Error("Element did not appear in time")); }, 5000);` to the promise executor and `clearTimeout(timer);` next to the `resolve` call.

Comment: @Bergi cool, helpful