# Create text and put it on page when it's loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a little problem with task for my new company. I need to write a script that basicly creates a html text and puts it on site using class selector (after a div to be sepcific). The problem is that we're using a custom CMS without any JS library so it has to be plain and the other obstacle I need to run only when element is loaded on page already (some kind of WaitForElement function is needed). JS noob here - can someone suggest a solution?
Thank you in advance

I've tried a simple solution:

```
node = document.getElementsByClassName('class1 class2');
node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>text</p>');
```

And I've put something like this:

```
function waitForElement(elementId, callBack) { window.setTimeout(function() { var element = document.querySelectorAll(elementId); if (element.length) { callBack(elementId, element);} else { waitForElement(elementId, callBack); }}}
```

However I'm struggling to merge those two and running them on site.

Comment: This is not a we code it for you site. What have you tried, what didn't work? If you have 0 clue ask your company to hire someone who know this kind of stuff.

Comment: I have tried a pretty simple and easy solution:
'node = document.getElementsByClassName('.class1.class2');
node.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<p>text</p>');'
However the problem is that I don't know how to make it run only after the element on page is loaded.

Comment: Add all this code you tried to the question itself, not to the comments.

Comment: There's not enough information to answer this question. Perhaps it's better to ask the CMS producer.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('.class1.class2')` - that's not how `getElementsByClassName` works. Read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Ahh I see, mismatched it with querySelector. Thx

Answer (score -1):

what CMS are you using?
Could you control the element?

I think you can use the `MutationObserver` API [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61511955/18620006).
or call the function after the element loaded

Comment: Unfortunetly it's a custom CMS made only for my company. Basicly I don't need to control the element. It's supposed to be small text added to a place on a site - it has to be in JS cuz that specific place is inaccessible otherwise. So I only have to write it in script

Comment: @Qhr Perhaps you should give your starting point code, so that we can help you better

Comment: Done, I've put it in my initial question. Sorry