# How to listen for iframe creation before running javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-books-api

I'm trying to wait for an iframe to be created before running some javascript, and i've tried a few methods but none seem to actually wait for the iframe - the error i'm getting in the console is `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'src')`.

The current code, below, tries to include the `waitForElm` function from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists), but 'm still getting the same error.

I need a value from within the iframe, so I want to wait for the iframe to load and then get the `src` of the iframe and use `fetch()` to call, parse with `DOMParser` and then get the item barcode.

It's for implementation of the Google Books Viewer API.

I also don't have access to the main html for the page, or directly to the iframe - which is why, for example, the creation of  a script tag for the google books api is via a function.

I'm quite new to javascript so apologies if there's some basic errors going on here.

```
// creates a script tag to load google books api
(function(){
const gb = document.createElement('script');
gb.type = 'text/javascript';
gb.src = 'https://www.google.com/books/jsapi.js';
gb.addEventListener('load', () => google.books.load());
document.head.appendChild(gb);
})();

//function to wait for iframe to load
function waitForElm(selector) {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
      return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
  }
  const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
      if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
          resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
      }
  });
  observer.observe(document.body, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
  });
});
}



app.controller('prmAlmaMashupAfterController', [function() {
this.$onInit = async function() {
  const frame = document.querySelector("#iFrameResizer0");
  fetch(frame.src)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(text => new DOMParser().parseFromString(text, 'text/html'))
    .then(document => {
      const bCode = document.getElementsByClassName('itemBarcode')[0].innerText || '';
      if (bCode) {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('viewerCanvas');
        const viewer = new google.books.DefaultViewer(canvas);
        viewer.load('NLS:' + bCode);
    console.log(bCode);
      } else {
        console.log('No barcode');
      }
    })
    .catch( e => {
      console.log('ERROR', e);
    });
}
}]);

//creates a div called viewerCanvas to hold the viewer
app.component('prmAlmaMashupAfter', {
bindings: { parentCtrl: '<' },
controller: 'prmAlmaMashupAfterController',
//  template: '<div id="viewerCanvas" style="height: 500px; width: 600px; border: 1px solid blue"></div>'
template: '<div id="viewerCanvas" style="height: 500px; width: 100%; margin: 1% auto !important;"></div>'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the iframe to load by adding a `load` event listener to the iframe:

```
frame.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // loaded
});
```

Comment: I don't have direct access to the iframe - is this still possible? Would I put the event listener after the creation of the frame variable but before the `fetch()`?

Comment: You can try adding it after line `const frame = document.querySelector("#iFrameResizer0");`