# Testcafe wait until element is clickable

Tags: javascript, testcafe

Is there a way to wait until element is clickable in Testcafe. For example in WebdriverIO we can use this

```
        const depInput = await $('.--departure');
        await browser.waitUntil(async () => depInput.isClickable());
        await depInput.click();
```

or use method waitForClickable().
I cannot find the way to do the same in Testcafe.

Comment: "wdio" is that a nice eatery near you?  Please if you use an abbreviation place a full description or reference with it.

Also consider adding whatever "testcafe" code you have tried and elaborate your one specific challenge with that.

Comment: Consider a mutation observer such as the answers here illustrate https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525071/125981

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Selector.filter` method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402753/reference/test-api/selector/filter) and the [timeout option](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402756/reference/test-api/selector/constructor#optionstimeout). For example:

```js
await t.click(Selector('.--departure', { timeout: 5000 }).filter(node => !node.disabled));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74795915/16217248) solution, but instead of `!node.disabled` use `!node.ariaDisabled`.

The `ariaDisabled` property will wait for the aria of selector to be enabled (click, insert, modify, ...) so it will look something like:

```
await t.click(Selector('.--departure', { timeout: 5000 }).filter(node => !node.ariaDisabled));
```