# How do I wait for an element to exist?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
                observer.disconnect();
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}

waitForElm('.some-class').then((elm) => {
    console.log('Element is ready');
    console.log(elm.textContent);
});
```

How does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61511955/21144884) from the popular question work? It returns an error for me:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

```
at content-script.js:14:18
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at waitForElm (content-script.js:2:12)
at content-script.js:21:1
```

It probably doesn't find the `document.body` element.

Comment: Looks like the `document.body` does not exist when you invoke the `observer.observe`. Have you tried to put the script at the end of your body tag?

Comment: I need it when my extension starts.

Comment: Ok if my suggested issue is the actual culprit, then listening to the body onload event would be an other option. But without a reproducable example one can only guess the issue, maybe add one.

Comment: Use `document` or `document.documentElement` instead of `document.body`.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you very much! I didn't know it was possible.