# Mutation Observer is working whenever I open console of developer tool otherwise it's not

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, vscode-extensions, mutation-observers

I am creating a firfox extension and try to hide some features in google documents one of the feature I am trying to hide is Insert -> Images -> Upload from computer. Upload from Computer is the element I want to hide which is the submenu item of images.

The element I want hide is dynamically loaded. So to observe the element I using mutation observer ,Upload from computer element does not have unique class name but it has unique id which is randomly generated which of no use.

So I used child elements class name which is also same for other elements but I combine that class name with aria-label property which is different  **.goog-menuitem-label[aria-label="Upload from computer u"]** and then **parentNode.parentNode** is used so that it can hide the parent of the parent of the above class.

**#docs-insert-menu** is the unique id of INSERT element

Here is the code :

```
// Function to hide the "Upload from Computer" option
function hideUploadOption() {
  const uploadOption = document.querySelector('.goog-menuitem-label[aria-label="Upload from computer u"]');
  if (uploadOption) {
    const uploadOPTION = uploadOption.parentNode.parentNode;
    if (uploadOPTION) {
      uploadOPTION.style.display = 'none';
      console.log('Upload option hidden');
    }
  }
}

const observerConfig = {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};
const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationsList) {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    // Check if the "Upload from Computer" option is added or modified
    if (mutation.target.matches('#docs-insert-menu')) {
      hideUploadOption();
    }
  }
});
const insertMenuItem = document.querySelector('#docs-insert-menu');
if (insertMenuItem) {
  // Observe changes in the "Insert" menu item
  observer.observe(insertMenuItem, observerConfig)
  hideUploadOption();

}
```

When I am loading the firefox Extension in firefox initally this code is not working if I click on the insert but as soon as I open console it will work. Can anyone tell me why it is working whenever I open console in developer tools and will it work if I use 'setTimeOut' and how does it work in this case?

Comment: If the window is resized when you open devtools and the page listens to the associated events, it may be adding the element conditionally depending on the window size.

Comment: Obviously you need to wait for the inserMenuItem to appear, see how to it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61511955/915844