# Using Javacript, Button element properly selected but .click() happening though event successfully triggered

Tags: javascript, click, userscripts

I am doing a Javascript userscript that can click on 'Voir plus' automatically on this [webpage](https://www.leboncoin.fr/jeux_video/2540607208.htm).
To select the button element 'Voir plus' I am using the great [waitForElem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61511955/20002542) function. This work great "console.log('Element is ready: ' + elm.textContent);" gives "Element is ready: Voir plus" 
but the click on 'Voir plus' does not happen, though I can see this in the console 'Click event triggered successfully.'  (and adding a setTimeout on elm.click() does not help).

```
function waitForElm(selector) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
        }

        const observer = new MutationObserver(mutations => {
            if (document.querySelector(selector)) {
                observer.disconnect();
                resolve(document.querySelector(selector));
            }
        });

        observer.observe(document.body, {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        });
    });
}

waitForElm('div[data-qa-id="adview_description_container"] > button').then((elm) => {
    if (elm) {
        console.log('Element is ready: ' + elm.textContent);
        try {
            elm.click();
            console.log('Click event triggered successfully.');
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error while clicking the element:', error);
        }
    } else {
        console.error('Element not found.');
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error while waiting for the element:', error);
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Comment: "I am doing a Javascript userscript that can click on 'Voir plus' automatically on this [webpage](https://www.leboncoin.fr/jeux_video/2540607208.htm)."
I want this userscript to click automatically on the button 'Voir plus' when the page is loading in order to display all the description of this ad.
For that, I have found the button, that's fine. But "elm.click()" is not opening the whole text description of the webpage.

Comment: What makes you think it's not working correctly?

Comment: What is being printed in the console? is the element correctly being printed?

Comment: "though I can see this in the console 'Click event triggered successfully.' ". When I look at the webpage, I can still see only a part of the description text and the 'Voir plus item is still present': https://i.imgur.com/sehePMy.png . The 'Click event triggered successfully' message is in the console: https://i.imgur.com/sFmlElP.png

Comment: As far as I can tell, none of the code in your question would modify the description text. Assuming it's included in `elm`'s click listener, please include that function as well as how the listener is attached to the element and called.

Comment: Yes none of the code modify the description text.  "Assuming it's included in elm's click listener, please include that function as well as how the listener is attached to the element and called." I do not understand, I am just asking a click action with "elm.click();" nothing else.

Comment: Why do you think that `elm.click()` should modify the description text?

Comment: I just wrote I need to click on it to display part of the text that is initially hidden (I do not modify anything).