# Jquery/JS get input value thats being changed by reactJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, wordpress

I am using WordPress and I have a form that has two input range sliders.

The form then calculates the two range slider values and displays the result as below:

```html
<input data-fraction-min="0" data-fraction="2" type="hidden" data-comma="yes" class="mf-input mf-input-calculation " name="mf-calculation" id="mf-input-calculation-2b21e15" data-equation="mf-volume * mf-value" aria-invalid="false" value="0">
```

```
<input
                data-fraction-min="0" 
                data-fraction="2"
                type="hidden"
                data-comma="yes"
                className="mf-input mf-input-calculation "
                name="mf-calculation"
                id="mf-input-calculation-2b21e15"
                data-equation="mf-volume * mf-value"
                                                    value=${ parent.state.formData['mf-calculation'] || '' }
                    onInput=${ parent.handleChange }
                    aria-invalid=${validation.errors['mf-calculation'] ? 'true' : 'false'}
                    ref=${ el => parent.activateValidation({"message":"This field is required.","required":false}, el) }
                            />
```

However, I am then trying to get the value of this input by ID when the value changes so I can do some custom JQuery calculations with the value.

However, the form (including the range sliders and calculated input field) is a plugin that is injected and handled by ReactJS and I have read multiple posts that trying to use Jquery will not work - apparently.

```php
function enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('customjs', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/customjs.js', array('jquery') );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_scripts');
```

```js
jQuery(function() {
    $('#mf-input-calculation-2b21e15').on("change paste keyup", function() {
        alert($(this).val()); // get the current value of the input field.
    });
});
```

**Another attempt**
I then tried to constantly check and store the value that is being shown as text inside a span - this achieved nothing, by not firing the alert.

```
jQuery(window.onload = function() {
    setInterval(
        function test() {
            var salestotal = $(".mf-input-calculation-total").text(); 
            alert(salestotal);
        },
        5000
    );
});

<span class="mf-input-calculation-total" data-prefix="£" data-suffix="">0</span>
```

Is there a way I can get the input value when it changes by JQuery or vanilla JS?  The alert is for testing purposes. Script is loading as expected using wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Are you able to share more information about what the plugin is and how you're using it?  Depending on the context, the JS for the plugin may be executing before the element is ever available.  You can wait until the element is available, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists

Comment: The plugin is MetForm (wpmet) - see pastebin of the calculation.php which is the file for this input type. 
https://pastebin.com/QwCWCM9h

Comment: I don't see how this is React related.  It seems like the markup is defined in PHP based off this pastebin, although I don't see something that matches the HTML in your post.  Are you able to expand on how the plugin is using React here, and where the second HTML snippet in your post came from?

Comment: Hi Nick, the second snippet is from page source and copied from there. 

The plugin developers both on forums and their website state their plugin is built using ReactJS. There is many files to the plugin which would be overkill to share via pastebin? In the pastebin link above, line 360 onward you can see the calcualtion input

Comment: Crucially, the key objective is being able to get the value from the input or the inner text of the span - as per snippets above. Even when running the JQuery after everything else has loded - it does not work. I did copy some of this code into a js fiddle / codepen and it did refrence an issue relating to DOM and use rootDOM or something or other...

Comment: Could DOMSubtreeModified funciton be of use?

Answer (score 0):

Would the following code help?

```
jQuery(document).on("change paste keyup", ".mf-input-calculation-total", function() {
    alert($(this).val()); // get the current value of the input field.
});
```

Instead of finding the control by id, jQuery is finding the control by class, even dynamically created ones after the DOM has been loaded. So if a new control is added to the page dynamically, with the class mf-input-calculation-total, any changes to that control should trigger the alert.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding to the question.

I tried this, and it did not do anything. 

The range sliders are part of the reactJS which I cannot control/edit - its a plugin. 
When the sliders change value the total is then displayed in the mf-input-calculation-total inside a span and also the input field mf-input-calculation-2b21e15 value is set to the same as what the span text is