# Can we bind hide event or does jquery have an "onhide" event

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far I tried [onHide() type event in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2857900/onhide-type-event-in-jquery)

Comment: what is expected, what happens ?

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.

Answer (score 3):

This plugin will be able to detect the style change and notify you: [jQuery Style Listener](http://techfoobar.com/jquery-style-listener/)

You can use it like:

```
$('#yourElement').styleListener({

    // the styles that you want to monitor for changes
    styles: ['display'],

    // function to be called when a monitored style changes 
    changed: function(style, newValue, oldValue, element) {

        if(style == 'display' && newValue == 'none') {
            // element got hidden, do your stuff
        }
    }

});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/vaxQX/

*Disclaimer*: I am the author of the plugin.

Comment: well, you need to improve the font size alerts :)

Comment: @roXon - Yes. Testing is still in progress. Also a few other styles like opacity in older versions of IE need fine tuning. :-)

Comment: I plan to make it compatible with almost all styles within 2 to 3 revisions.

Comment: well, wht to say but a brave and good job. +1 Keep up with your work! thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a callback function on the function that gets hidden.

```
$('div').hide(function(){
    // do something
});
```

Not sure if this will work for what you want, but the function will only fire once hide is complete.

Answer (score 0):

you can use http://api.jquery.com/promise/ :

http://jsbin.com/evajiv/1/edit

```
$('#test').click(function(){
   $(this).hide();      // I USED .fadeTo() in the demo
   $(this).promise().done(function(  ) {
       alert( 'HIDDEN!' );
   });
});
```

or in a classic way:

```
function fn(){
   alert('DONE!');
}

$('#test').click(function(){
   $(this).hide(fn);  // use callback
});
```

http://jsbin.com/evajiv/3/edit