# Make one element disappear when another element disappears

Tags: javascript, jquery

Context: I am making a small jQuery library for modals (in-window popups): https://github.com/hypesystem/d_modal.js

When creating a new modal, it is possible to also fade the page. This is done by adding a div with a semi-transparent black background.

When the modal is removed I want the "fade" to disappear as well. But **not just** when the modal is `.remove()`'d - I want the fade to disappear in the same way as the modal on any action that makes the modal disappear: `fadeOut()`, `hide()`, etc.

Here is a jsFiddle to test in (if you have any ideas): http://jsfiddle.net/n5fqS/

What I'm looking for is *one* solution that handles all the cases.

Comment: Is the second `<div>` always called the same thing?

Comment: The second div will always have the class `.blackness`, but there may be several of it (if several modals with fade exist). But you should be able to assume that it is just called `#div-two` as in the fiddle - at the time of creation I have a reference to the unique DOM element.

Comment: Update: Potential solution, hiding the original jQuery implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2857952/1080564 - this seems very cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer seems to be: jQuery does not emit events on hide.

In order to combat this, I have used [the best solution I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2857952/1080564), and started an open project to enable sending of the required events: https://github.com/hypesystem/showandtell.js

This should cover, at the moment, the most common use-cases. Any feedback on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

there are many ways of hidding elements (removing content of div, changing css "display" property, fadeOut(), hide(), etc, etc) and Jquery does not have a universal event listener that would group all these events.  I think you will have to manually trigger a "hide" event as a callback function in all the places where your first div is being hidden.  For example:

```
$(".dismiss").click(function() {
    $("#div-one").hide(function(){
          $(this).trigger('hide');
    });
});
```

Then you only have to have once the event handler:

```
$("#div-one").on('hide', function(){ 
        //code that hides my second div 
)};
```

Of course, you will have to manually add the trigger every place where relevant. So its not "the one solution".

Comment: I got that far earlier. Again, the question is if a general purpose solution exists. Your answer is "not as far as I know". Well, not as far as I know, either... but this doesn't get me any further :) Thanks for your time, though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jquery dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but this isn't really a solution for my question. I will look into how jQuery UI does it, though.

Comment: Update: Actually, jQuery UI dialogs do __not__ provide the functionality I am asking for. See http://jsfiddle.net/7LQhP/1/ - when calling `hide()` on the dialog, only the inner text is hidden, and definitely not the fade in the background.

jQuery UI forces you to use their own handlers.

Answer (score -1):

try like this

```
$(".dismiss").click(function() {
    $("#div-one").hide(function(){
          $("#div-two").hide('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: As I specified, I would like one solution that works for every case. With your answer I would have to make a handler for each of the cases.