# jquery capture onToggle

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have set of DIVs and i render CheckBoxList in each of them. Number of DIVs and number of CheckBoxLists are dynamic. Each div has a button associated with it which will toggle the visibility of that particular DIV.

Every time user clicks on a checkbox, i need to display the text of that checkbox in one label. I am thinking that i shud attach an event on the DIV's toggle event so that when the div becomes visible, i can bind a function on the click event of checkboxes inside that div which will display the text of clicked checkbox.

I am struggling to find a way to capture when the div becomes visible or invisible. How do i know which div is being displayed at a given time?

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What excactly do you mean with toggled?

Comment: What "toggling" are you talking about? You mean the visibility? If so, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/941113/jquery-javascript-dom-visibility-event

Comment: I am talking abt making div show or hide by calling .toggle() event.

Comment: @Bauer: It does what i want to do but i am looking for the native code. I think if JQuery gives toggle functionality then there shud be a way to attach a function to it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind event handler / actions to them at any instance:

```
$("div#theContainerId").find(":visible").each(function(/*Do Something*/));
```

If you want to bind some other action (other than hide/show) during the toggle(), do this:

```
$(".toggleTarget").toggle(function(){$(this).hide(); /* add more actions here */}, function(){$(this).show(); /* add more actions here */});
```

Comment: $(".toggleTarget").toggle(function(){$(this).hide(); /* Here i will find the checkboxes inside toggleTarget and bind event handlers to them*/},

Thanks a lot.....

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see whether a div is visible or not on startup or at intervals.

[this selector will tell you that](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/).

after that you need to keep track of who is hiding it and have it call a function i think

@bauer's link would work i think but would possibly be expensive.

if this is not what you want then please expand your question.