# Run some DOM manipulation when an element becomes visible in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Is it possible to elegantly run some code when some element becomes visible and another piece of code when it hides? I want to apply swipeable scroll areas here and there in a single-page app and it's only possible when elements are visible.

Comment: See if this helps any: http://stackoverflow.com/a/941161/215945

Comment: googling `MutationObserver` may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.1.4 has added animation support into the framework. See [here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/04/animation-in-angularjs.html) for more information.

You may be able to achieve your effect using a css3 transition, although I'm not exactly sure based on the information in your question. Alternatively you could create an animation in Javascript that will run on ng-show/ng-hide:

```
<div data-ng-hide="hidden == true" data-ng-animate="'myAnimation'">
  ...
</div>
<div data-ng-show="hidden == false" data-ng-animate="'myAnimation'">
  ...
</div>
```

...

```
//you can inject stuff!
myModule.animation('myAnimation-show', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return { 
    setup : function(element) {
      //this is called before the animation
    },
    start : function(element, done, memo) {
      //this is where the animation is expected to be run
    }
  };
}]);

myModule.animation('myAnimation-hide', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  return { 
    setup : function(element) {
      //this is called before the animation
    },
    start : function(element, done, memo) {
      //this is where the animation is expected to be run
    }
  };
}]);
```

**EDIT:**

See an example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/eQUFfWakA0J2tnLYjl5G?p=preview).